# Find the Rank 01 Matching element against the Given Key word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have two tables, Table two with code and Key words.

[image]

Table 01

[image]

Table 01 With combination of Key words, SO need to find the height matching row of each description and need to give the rank one matching code as code against the Description.

For Easy reference I added video in LOOM, please refer below video.

https://www.loom.com/share/fbabeb8f190b44c7b88e82f90770c8eb?sid=5852e721-c471-4fbf-a0dd-191235e4a2fa

I created G- Sheet as well, If it is easy, please provide the solution on that.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OvxT1gpkUncEvPxLaf_ob6qqwijciEQ0AjfPn7qJyT0/edit?usp=sharing

Best regard
Indika

Comment: Try: `=LET(
a,HSTACK($D$2:$D$8,BYROW(SIGN(IFERROR(XMATCH($E$2:$K$8,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")),0)),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))),
@SORT(a,2,-1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then this would work. Assuming there is no *Excel Constraints*, i.e. we assume as per your tags you are using **MS365**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(
a,HSTACK($D$2:$D$8,
BYROW(SIGN(IFERROR(XMATCH($E$2:$K$8,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")),0)),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))),
@SORT(a,2,-1))
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>MAP()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(a,
LET(b,TEXTSPLIT(a," "),
d,BYROW(SIGN(IFERROR(XMATCH(E2:K8,b),0)),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c))),
e,HSTACK(D2:D8,d),@SORT(e,2,-1))))
```

---

Another alternative approach without using <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(
     a,N(IFERROR(XMATCH($E$2:$K$8,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")),0)<>0),
     b,HSTACK($D$2:$D$8,MMULT(a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),,,0))),
     @SORT(b,2,-1))
```

---

If you want a single array formula.

[image]

---

```
=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(m,LET(
       a,N(IFERROR(XMATCH($E$2:$K$8,TEXTSPLIT(m," ")),0)<>0),
       b,HSTACK($D$2:$D$8,MMULT(a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),,,0))),
       @SORT(b,2,-1))))
```

---

Comment: When I Try to apply it , Warning appear as Older version, But I am using 365. 

So, If G - sheet is workable I am happy to use the same for G- Sheet

=@
LET(
a,HSTACK($D$2:$D$8,
BYROW(SIGN(IFERROR(XMATCH(@$E$2:$K$8,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")),0)),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))),SORT(a,2,-1))

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OvxT1gpkUncEvPxLaf_ob6qqwijciEQ0AjfPn7qJyT0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I created G - sheet If possible Please update the formula on that.

Comment: @indikaprasanna you need to press `No` instead of `Yes`

Comment: @indikaprasanna download the excel from here. **[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjRAC_QxNBmTXG5Xv?e=BZxtVP)**

Comment: Its working well, Thanks a lot for all support

Comment: @indikaprasanna glad to know that.

Comment: Hello Mayukh,
If I need to get the rank 2 as 2nd Option , Please help to get that as well.

Better if you can support for G-Sheet as well.

Best regard
Indika

Comment: That is a different question, you need to create a new post.

Comment: Hello, Sure I will do

Comment: I need formula for Excel sheet as well, So please help to add the sperate formula to get the Excel function for rank 02 as well.

Created new POST for that

Comment: I have already posted the formula in your sheet. its the same formula that would work in excel. only replace `SPLIT()` with `TEXTSPLIT()`