# Find the Rank 02 Matching element against the Given Key word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula

I have two tables, Table two with code and Key words.

[image]

Now I need to get the rank 02 separately

[image]

Table 01 With combination of Key words, SO need to find the 2nd Rank of height matching row of each description and need to give the rank two matching code as code against the Description.

Best regard
Indika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much difference between the last post and this one, you need to wrap the <kbd>SORT()</kbd> function within <kbd>TAKE()</kbd> & <kbd>TOROW()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=LET(
     a,N(IFERROR(XMATCH($E$2:$K$8,TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")),0)<>0),
     b,HSTACK($D$2:$D$8,MMULT(a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),,,0))),
     TOROW(TAKE(SORT(b,2,-1),2,1)))
```

---

Reference to last post of OP: **[Find the Rank 01 Matching element against the Given Key word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76613663/find-the-rank-01-matching-element-against-the-given-key-word)**

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B2`

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A6,LAMBDA(m,b,VSTACK(m,LET(
       a,N(IFERROR(XMATCH($E$2:$K$8,TEXTSPLIT(b," ")),0)<>0),
       c,HSTACK($D$2:$D$8,MMULT(a,SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),,,0))),
       CHOOSECOLS(TOROW(SORT(c,2,-1)),1,3))))),1)
```

---

Comment: Thanks a Lot for your Support. It help me lot.